# Rendering form in comment controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to render my questions form partial on my posts show page.  Right now when i enter text and press post it redirects to the default form and keeps the text.

I am rendering the form like so:

```
<%= render :partial => "questions/form", :locals => {:question => @comment.questions.new} %>
```

The questions controller:

```
def create
@comment = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
@question = @comment.questions.new(question_params)
end
```

the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@comment, Question.new] do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<%= render :partial => "questions/form", :locals => {:question => @comment.questions.new} %>`

this part `, :locals => {:question => @comment.questions.new}` seems to be useless cause you override it anyway in the form partial with `Question.new` in the `simple_form_for`.

`create` action should have a save call and `redirect` to somewhere if `save` successfull or not.

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
  @question = @comment.questions.new(question_params)
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to :back
  else
    # somet actions here
  end
end
```

Comment: Took out ':question => @comment.questions.new' but it's still not working.  Is def create in comments controller or questions? Right now its in questions.

Comment: if you want you can tell me your skype name and I'll add you to contacts and we'll fix it using teamviewer.. won't take long.

Comment: Thanks for the offer but I just figured it out!  I was validating a field that i didn't have in my form. Simple fix. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I may have a different problem for you to tackle if you want. I remember you helping me with a past acts_as_votable problem so you might know the fix for this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21080824/user-get-voted-comment-and-post.  Thanks again!

Comment: join this chat  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45092/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-21059307-rendering-form-in-comment-controller