# @user.get_voted comment and post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

On a users profile page i am displaying all the comments that the user has upvoted like this (using the acts_as_votable_gem):

```
 def show
 @uservotes = @user.get_voted Comment
 end
```

Comments all belong_to a Post. In the view I am trying to get the comment as well as the comments post like this:

```
 <% @uservotes.each do |comment| %>

 <%= comment.post.title %>
 <%= comment.title %>

 <% end %>
```

It gets the comment.title fine but gives me this for the comment.post.title:

```
undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
```

If i do just:

```
<%= comment.post %>
```

it returns an id:

```
#<Post:0x0000010a956658>
```

Comment: are you sure that the code is `@uservotes = @user.get_voted Comment` not `@uservotes = @user.get_voted comment` notice the **c** in `comment` ?

Comment: Yep with a capital C.

Comment: yeah i've read that in the docs... are you sure that you added `has_many :comments` to the post model ? like you added `belong_to Post` to the comment model ?

Comment: I think i amy have found my problem. In the docs it says the get_voted is for an individual model. They give another way - find_voted_items, but that gave me the same error. https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable - for reference.

Comment: can you print the comment in the view .. and add it here ? so we can debug it ?

Comment: By comment in the view do you mean the output of <%= comment %>? BTW comment.post returns a value if that helps.

Comment: If comment.post return value (the Id of the post not relation) then the problem is in configuring the relation of the model to load the data (try adding has_many to the comment model)... In other words the post is loaded as only Id not the whole object... So you have to configure the comment model to load the post not just its ID

Comment: The comment model has 'belongs_to post'. Is that correct?

Comment: could you print post.id instead of post ?... in the post you add `has_many :comments` and in the comment model you add `belongs_to :post`

Comment: Post.id gives the same error and yeah the models have those lines.

Answer (score 0):

The `post` value of `comment` is `nil` when the error is raised. In order for anyone to help you determine the *reason* for that, you'd have to share information about the definition/results of `get_voted`, what's in a `Comment`, etc.

Comment: I think it's probably nil because of the way i'm getting the comments in with get_voted.